# Techniques I can use to optimise my C++ code further?

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm working on loading PNG files. I know there are existing libraries, but I'm doing this for learning purposes. Previously, I was using [LodePNG](https://lodev.org/lodepng/), which is a great library that performs really well.

I have a large PNG, 2048x2048 pixels with 8 bits of depth. I load it ten times with my code, and average out the time it takes (measured with std::chrono). I do the same with LodePNG. LodePNG is built in the solution so it's using the same compiler flags as my own code.

Initially I found that my library would take ~8000ms on average to load the image whereas LodePNG takes on average ~800ms. 10 times longer!

Using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/1862823) I have managed to reduce my execution time down to ~3100ms. This was through a series of improvements:

1. Used `std::uint_fast32_t` sort of types in place of `std::uint32_t` where it made sense
2. Refactoring some parts of code several times
3. Replacing some `std::map`s with `std::array`s or `std::vector`s where I could (I naively used maps when it wasn't required)
4. Enabled Link-Time Optimisation (which didn't help LodePNG speed but shaved 100ms off mine)

However, I've found now that the random interrupting and checking the backtrace in GDB is revealing the same bits of code over and over again:

1. Calls to `std::copy`
2. Calls to the creation of `std::vector`s (I'm using a custom memory allocator that performs better, it's also being used for pointer creation)

Which aren't things I can improve upon. LodePNG is mostly C-like code, it doesn't use any Standard Library headers. But, I always read that using these libraries shouldn't be any slower... but well here I am.

My question is, what else can I do to identify hot-spots and fix them? Any  techniques that would be appropriate? Ideally they would work on Windows.

I'm using GCC 10.2 through MingW64 in MSYS2.

Comment: Questions about coding and low-level optimization techniques are a way better fit for Stackoverflow than for this site (but when you decide to move it over, don't forget to delete your question here first, for not making a cross-post).

Comment: ... moreover, asking for tool recommendations is off-topic on this site, as well as on Stackoverflow.

Comment: FWIW, when your profiling technique revealed `std::copy` and `std::vector::ctor` as a bottleneck, maybe you should look for ways to reduce the number of calls to these methods? For example, by doing more things inline? This is pretty hard to tell without seeing the code. But don't understand my comment as a request to post your code here - codereview.stackexchange may be the best place for this.

Comment: Manually interrupting and checking backtraces in GDB is a "poor man's profiler". So get yourself a decent profiler (I hope that exists for C++) that can show you the call tree over the total runtime, annotated with the percentage of time spent in the various functions and (optionally) the number of calls to that function. Identify the bottlenecks (including the callers chain where they are called from), and then think about either local optimizations or about algorithm improvements.

Comment: Did you try to make use of "vector::reserve" to avoid the number of reallocations?

Comment: First and foremost is learn and use gprof against optimized release builds. Only people who have no serious production pressure to produce optimized code try to determine their hotspots with debugging breakpoints. But one of the biggest bottlenecks I see in file I/O in C++ is the use of the standard I/O streams, including `fstream`. I do like their interfaces far better (they're way safer) but they're ridiculously slower than the cstdio functions like `sscanf`. Things like using `uint32_fast_t` is really micro and I don't think those will be your first options if you're 10x slower.

Comment: ... and measuring your results with the profiler in hand. I think you will get better responses though (voting-wise) as well as maybe answering 90% of your own question with a profiler in hand, and posting the profiler results along with your Q.

Comment: Another tendency among C++ devs if they aren't careful is to allocate a whole lot more on the heap and incur far more cache misses than necessary. `std::vector` performs handsomely, and sometimes outperforms your average C solutions for large growing sequences whose potential capacities can't be anticipated in advance. But there's also a tendency among more ordinary C++ devs to use things like std::vector to output results from a function that might only average a dozen elements in size called repeatedly which needlessly allocates and deallocates memory repeatedly on the free store.

Answer (score 6):

The advice that the C++ standard libraries aren't slower than C code is true *when the same operations are performed*.

A quick look at the LodePNG code shows that is loads a file like this:

1. determine the file size
2. allocate a buffer large enough to store the entire file
3. read the file into the buffer in one go

Based on your description, I assume you are loading a file like this:

1. start with an empty `std::vector`
2. while not eof

   1. read one (or a few) bytes
   2. append the read byte(s) to the vector

These algorithms are not equivalent and may thus give a different performance.

A lot of the `std::copy` calls may come from re-allocations that the vector does while it is growing in size. But if you know what the final size of the vector will be, you can prevent all of those by telling the vector up front to reserve enough memory to store the total number of elements needed.

Such algorithmic changes are what you should first look at when you want to improve the performance of your code, as that is where the biggest wins can be made.